# Try every option for a command and make anagrams out of the successful ones

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

**What I have:** I am trying to find what words you can make out of Linux command options like `ls -cat` or `ps -elf`. To do that I am iterating through an array of 50 commands, trying to run each with flags -[a-z] and then making anagrams out of the successful options. It is working and here is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Pull in a list of common Linux commands
commandList=( $(
  curl 'http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/11/50-linux-commands/' 2> /dev/null \
    | grep -o '<h3>\([0-9].*[a-z][a-z][a-z].*\)</h3>' \
    | awk '{ print $(NF-2) }' \
    | sed -nr '/rm|wget|less|shutdown|<h3>/!p'
) );

# Pipe successful "$command -$option" pairs to 'an' to generate anagrams
for command in ${commandList[@]} ; do
    (for option in {a..z} ; do
        timeout -k 5 5 "$command" -"$option" > /dev/null 2>&1;
            if (($? == 0)); then
                printf "$option" | tr -d '\n'
            else
                    :
            fi
    done) | xargs an -w -d saneWordlist -m 3 2> /dev/null \
          | sed 's/^/\ '$command' -/' >> commandOptions.log
done
```

**Self Criticism:**
I know it is unreliable to rely on exit codes that are not at all consistent and just hoping the devs used 0 to indicate success. I also know I abused `sed` and `awk` a lot. I also didn't try to write this in a very POSIX-y way.

**What I want help on:**
I am not too worried about the web scraping part, I know it is cheap and messy. But, how can I improve the core section where I misuse `sed` and `awk` so much? I know there cleaner ways to accomplish what I want, but can't think of anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the commands in the web scraping part can be simplified.

Instead of `awk '{ print $(NF-2) }'`, why not simply `awk '{ print $2 }'`?

Instead of `sed -nr '/rm|wget|less|shutdown|<h3>/!p'`, it would be simpler and more portable to use `grep -vE 'rm|wget|less|shutdown|<h3>'`.

Using a Bash array is a bit overkill,
because the output of the pipeline is guaranteed to be one word per line,
no other white space.
So using a simple variable and word splitting should do the job, and simpler:

```
commandList=$(
  curl 'http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/11/50-linux-commands/' 2> /dev/null \
    | grep -o '<h3>\([0-9].*[a-z][a-z][a-z].*\)</h3>' \
    | awk '{ print $2 }' \
    | grep -vE 'rm|wget|less|shutdown|<h3>'
)

for command in $commandList; do
```

---

Many improvements are possible here:

> ```
> timeout -k 5 5 "$command" -"$option" > /dev/null 2>&1;
>     if (($? == 0)); then
>         printf "$option" | tr -d '\n'
>     else
>             :
>     fi
> ```

In Bash, you can use `&>/dev/null` to redirect both `stdout` and `stderr`.

Since `$option` only contains a single letter and `printf` doesn't print a trailing newline like `echo`, the `tr` command there is pointless.
The double-quotes around `$option` are also unnecessary.
The empty `else` branch should be removed.

Instead of using a condition on `$?`, you could use the command itself directly:

```
if timeout -k 5 5 "$command" -$option &> /dev/null; then
    printf $option
fi
```

---

You could rewrite the final `sed` simpler using double-quotes:

```
sed "s/^/ $command -/" >> commandOptions.log
```

I also removed a pointless `\` from in front of a space within the quoted expression.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your review!